# Intellij warning "StringBuffer.toString() in concatenation"

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, stringbuilder, intellij-14

If you enable all inspections under the heading "Performance issues", you'll get a warning (as in the title) about the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Two");
String s = "One" + sb.toString();
```

I realise the `toString()` is unnecessary, but in what way is it a performance issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in using a `StringBuilder` if you're going to use the string concatenation operator (`+`), which creates a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes, leading to the creation of two `StringBuilder` objects instead of one. You can simply re-use the `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("One");
sb.append("Two");
String s = sb.toString();
```

The original code is equivalent to:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Two");
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("One");
String s = sb2.append(sb.toString()).toString();
```

Another aspect related to the warning (which honestly has less to do with performance than code optimization) is that the `toString()` is redundant when used with the `+` operand. This is because the compiler will automatically call the `toString()`. This is what you already guessed in your question, and is explained in the Java Language Specification:

(from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type `String`, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

where [section 5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) says:

> - If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the `toString` method is `null`, then the string `"null"` is used instead.

Comment: That is correct in general, but Intellij IDEA suggests and offers to change my code to `String s = "One" + sb;` (And after it does that, the warning goes away.)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes the `toString()` is redundant. It will be done behind the scenes as well. Not a performance issue but code optimization.

Comment: I've just realised how it's a performance issue. You're half-way there. Clue: the toString() call _isn't_ done behind the scenes if you don't call it explicitly.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I think `toString()` will be called anyway. The `StringBuilder` may call `append(Object)` behind the scenes. But this in turn will call `toString()` of the passed object (which in this case is the `StringBuilder`).

Comment: Nope, have a look at _all_ the overloads of `StringBuilder.append();` ;-)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You want to say it calls `append(StringBuilder)`? I'm not sure it will. You can check this easily. Put a breakpoint on all `append` methods and see which ones are called. I still think `append(Object)` is called.

Comment: It will call `append(StringBuilder)` or, more accurately, `append(CharSequence)`. `"One" + sb` gets compiled into `StringBuilder("One").append(sb).toString()`. It will call the `append(CharSequence)` overload. And that uses the data in the StringBuilder directly without creating an unnecessary intermediate String object.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Maybe it depends on the implementation... I tried it (with Java 7) and `append(Object)` gets invoked.

Comment: You're right! (At least in Java 7) - I wonder why it misses the opportunity to call `append(CharSequence)` since the compiler surely knows sb is a CharSequence.

Answer (score 0):

2 things here:

1. "One" + "Two" is the fastest way to do this.  It will take 0 nanoseconds at run time (the concatenation happens at compile time.)  But IntelliJ is not intellejent enough to make that connection.
2. It's probably calling this out because it's a weird thing to do since + can generate lots of objects if you are doing it in a loop and StringBuilder is one way to avoid that issue.

Comment: Regarding point 1, I over-simplified my sample code: The StringBuilder is actually used to build a string with several appends in a loop, before being passed to the + operator.